# Angular testing using jest and spectator fails TypeError: testing.waitForAsync is not a function

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest, angular2-testing, angular-spectator

I am using
Angular CLI: 10.2.3
Node: 12.22.1
npm: 6.14.12

I am new to angular. I am trying to use jest for testing angular code (project runs fine without any errors, now adding some tests where I see issue). I have many custom services so using Spectator to mock them. I have few tests, one of them (failing) is below.

A simple component test is as below.

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { MyComponent } from './my.component';

import { BasicAuthService } from './../../services/auth/basic-auth.service';
import { RefdataService } from '../../services/common/refdata.service';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import {MyUploadService} from '../../services/data/my-upload.service';

import { 
  createComponentFactory, 
  createHostFactory, 
  Spectator, 
  SpectatorHost
} from '@ngneat/spectator/jest';

import { ObjectKeysPipe } from '../../pipes/common/object-keys.pipe';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

import { MockProxy, mock, mockReset } from 'jest-mock-extended'; 
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

//Create a MatDialog mock class 
export class MatDialogMock {
  
  open() {
    return {
      afterClosed: () => of({action: true})
    };
  }
}

describe('MyUploadComponent', () => {

  let spectator: Spectator<MyUploadComponent>;

  const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    component: MyUploadComponent,
    declarations: [MyUploadComponent, ObjectKeysPipe],
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule,
              MatSnackBarModule,
              RouterTestingModule
             ],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    mocks: [BasicAuthService,
            RefdataService,
            MyUploadService
           ],
    detectChanges: false
  });

  beforeEach(()=> {
    spectator= createComponent();
    spectator.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {    
    expect(spectator.component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 FAIL  src/app/components/my-upload/my-upload.component.spec.ts
  ? Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: testing.waitForAsync is not a function

      38 |   let spectator: Spectator<MyUploadComponent>;
      39 |
    > 40 |   const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
         |                           ^
      41 |     component: MyUploadComponent,
      42 |     declarations: [MyUploadComponent, ObjectKeysPipe],
      43 |     imports: [HttpClientTestingModule,

      at Object.baseCreateComponentFactory [as createComponentFactory] (node_modules/projects/spectator/src/lib/spectator/create-factory.ts:77:5)
      at Object.createComponentFactory (node_modules/projects/spectator/jest/src/lib/spectator.ts:19:10)
      at src/app/components/my-upload/my-upload.component.spec.ts:40:27
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:386:30)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:143:47)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/components/my-upload/my-upload.component.spec.ts:36:1)
```

I am unable to find anything related to this error. I am not using explicitly waitForAsync. What should be the issue here?

Comment: Try to update `@ngneat/spectator` to version 7.2.0

Comment: Yes it is latest, still getting the same error. Following is from package-lock.json (still I uninstalled locally and globally and downloaded latest.

 "@ngneat/spectator": {
      "version": "7.2.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@ngneat/spectator/-/spectator-7.2.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-FUdQqXCQEBwxAX33ZbU7h25cMKT24kesIX8ggiSHfGyyAJbYSJwZkzWLLpLgJqSQcPbe1dLCxCGA6tpIkGF9rg==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "@testing-library/dom": "7.26.5",
        "jquery": "3.6.0",
        "replace-in-file": "^6.2.0",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0"
      }

Comment: Ok, since you're using `Angular 10`, try installing version 5.13.0. That should be the approximate version of when Angular 10 and ng-neat both released. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngneat/spectator?activeTab=readme . Check out the versions tab in that link.